# Is there a way to know when applicationSignificantTimeChange is trigger?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I'm currently working on an app that tracks time and I am facing a problem.
Problem is when I change the timezone on my testing device (iphone 5c) it will indeed trigger the `applicationSignificantTimeChange` method.

But the thing is I want to know when the exact time when the timezone was changed

(something like :timezone changed at 11h utc). Is there a way to know that like a message system or something that i can retrieve on my app?

I thought the `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` could do that but I didn't manage to do it, either i didn't get it right or it is not possible with this notification.

Any help would be welcome, thanks

Comment: Did you try changing the time and date settings in your simulator. When you come back to app, it should trigger the notification right away.

Comment: I rephrased my question, the notification is triggered like i said, but i don't want the notification, i want to know at what time the change in timezone occured, the apple documentation is unclear on whether this is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not rely on receiving the message `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` when the event *actually occurs*. If your app is suspended, it will only receive the last notification when it returns to the foreground. You could create an `NSDate` object when the message is delivered, but it would be *the time your app was made aware of the change*, not when the actual change occurred on the device.

Apple's documentation for `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` states:

> **Discussion**
>
> Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of
>   midnight, an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to
>   daylight savings time. The delegate can implement this method to
>   adjust any object of the app that displays time or is sensitive to
>   time changes.
>
> Prior to calling this method, the app also posts a
>   `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` notification to give
>   interested objects a chance to respond to the change.
>
> If your app is currently suspended, this message is queued until your
>   app returns to the foreground, at which point it is delivered. If
>   multiple time changes occur, only the most recent one is delivered.

The `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` is also unhelpful. The `object` property is the `UIApplication` object and no `userInfo` object is provided.

Comment: Oh, i thought maybe something wasn't put in the documentation and there might be a workaround :/ well too bad for me.
Thanks for the answer